# Email Sender Different In Lightning Vs. Classic

Tags: lightning, email, email-template, salesforce-classic

If a user sends an email from an Opportunity the sender is different in Lightning. In Classic the sender is the name of user with the org-wide email address as email while in Lightning only the org-wide email address is being used as the sender - the name of the user is not shown.

To reproduce set up an org-wide email address and then have the user set their `Email Name` to `MyCompany | John Doe` and their `Email Address` to `service@mycompany.com` (the org-wide email address). You can find both under **Settings --> Email --> My Email Settings**. Then you just send a simple email from the Opportunity, selecting `MyCompany | John Doe <service@mycompany.com>` as the sender.

If you now compare the email header from both tests - this is what you should get.

**Classic**

```
From MyCompany | John Doe <service@mycompany.com>
Subject Test Classic
MIME-Version 1.0
Content-Type multipart/alternative;
X-Sender postmaster@salesforce.com
X-SFDC-EmailCategory emailAuthorEmail
```

**Lightning**

```
From "service@mycompany.com" <service@mycompany.com>
Subject Test Lightning
MIME-Version 1.0
Content-Type multipart/mixed;
X-Priority 3
X-Sender postmaster@salesforce.com
X-SFDC-EmailCategory apiSingleMail
```

What I find odd are the missing quotes in the from address of the test in Classic - but aside from that you can clearly see that they are different. Then we have some minor differences in the `MIME-Version` etc. - but the most interesting thing seems to be `X-SFDC-EmailCategory` where we have `emailAuthorEmail` in Classic vs. `apiSingleMail` in Lightning. The first option kind of sounds like an email that is "authored" by the user as it was set up in their email settings (see above).

Maybe the difference is always there? Maybe the problem only becomes apparent when the user has set up their email settings with an org-wide email address? Maybe there's an option that I missed? I don't know. Did anybody else notice the same? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: _When this user sends an email_ - unclear on how this happens. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @identigral As far as I observed it happens everywhere but most of the time the email is sent from an Opportunity.

Comment: @identigral Thanks for your input. I finally got all the information from the users an dug into it a little bit more so I could rephrase the whole question.

Comment: Looks like a possible bug or a degradation/change of behavior. You should open a case with Support.

Comment: I did open a case. They could confirm the behavior when using an org-wide email address. Let's see if this is a bug or a feature. Thanks for the help!

Comment: They finally could reproduce the issue and noted that there's a problem. Let's see what they find.

Comment: Thank you for opening a case and closing the loop here.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in the email picker for the email sender that deduplicates entries (org-wide vs. user) incorrectly. The issue has now been escalated but no further update so far. I will hopefully will be able to post an answer here.

Comment: The bug could now be reproduced and an internal bug ticket has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed a bug:

> A bug is now created to remove the Discrepancy in the Form Name for the emails sent from Lightning Experience when the use email address matches with an Org Wide email address. By Design only the Org wide email address will should be available in the From address field when composing an email on a non-case objects in case of duplicate email address.

It seems this only happens in a particular scenario when

- you're in Lightning
- and the user's email address is set to an email that is not yours
- and the email address being used matches an org-wide email address.

A bug ticket has been created by Salesforce but sadly there's no workaround in the meantime. I will update this answer when the bug is fixed.